# How to correct the "connection.readyState" of mongoose on test cases from "connecting" to "connected"?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, mongoose, mocha.js

I have created a model of users(registration) in mongoose. This model is accessed from test case created in mocha as well as register form from front end. The new user can be saved from register form  through front end, but the test case written in mocha can't be saved.

While I check through the code the `connection.readyState` of mongoose is `2`(`connecting`) on test case and `1`(`connected`) for user register form.

**models/users.js**

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');

mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/test');

console.log('conn ready:  '+mongoose.connection.readyState);
// "conn ready: 2"  i.e connecting for test case as well as from user register form 

var Schema = mongoose.Schema,
    ObjectId = Schema.ObjectId,
    UserSchema = new Schema({
       // schemas
    });

UserSchema.statics.newUser = function (uname, email, pass) {
    var instance = new User();
    instance.uname  = uname;
    instance.email  = email;
    instance.pass   = pass;
    console.log("conn state: "+mongoose.connection.readyState); 
    // "conn state: 2"  i.e connecting for test case. But  1  i.e connected for  user register form 

    instance.save(function (err) {
      // Do rest
    });
};

var User = mongoose.model('User', UserSchema);

exports.User = User;
```

How to correct the `connection.readyState` of mongoose on test cases?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem lies on parameter passing of `it` method in mocha test file. I forget to put the `done` parameter for `it` method in test case and doesn't call passed function `done()` at the end of test case.

```
describe('User', function () {
    it('new user create', function (done) {
                                    ^^^^   
        User.newUser(
            'test','test@test.com', 'test123',
            function (err, user) {
                should.not.exist(err);
                done();
                ^^^^^^
            }
        );
    });
});
```